# Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp

Tags: java

I got that error  while running the program, below are few more details

I have created a folder on C drive with name as `myapplication`
I have saved the code with file name as `HelloWorldApp.java` using notepad.

At the command prompt I have `c:\myapplication>`
Then I am typing the following command `java -cp . HelloWorldApp`, below is how it looks

```
c:\myapplication>java -cp . HelloWorldApp
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldApp
```

Kindly help me solve this, so that I can proceed further.

Comment: You are aware that you have to compile the file before running, right?

Comment: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/

Comment: Show the code of HelloWorldApp.java to complete the question!

Comment: Java is not like Perl or Python or Ruby, you do not run the *.java file. You run a *.class file which has to be generated with javac from the .java file. If you have compiled it and just left that out of the question - make sure that the filename and class name inside the file match. That is you need class HelloWorldApp {} .

Comment: class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); //
    }
}

Comment: This question is off-topic because OP forgot to compile his code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to compile file

```
c:\myapplication>javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

then

```
c:\myapplication>java HelloWorldApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at running the javac command first to compile your class. A class file should be generated which will work with your java command.

Comment: I have now installed javac properly, and I can now see the version of javac in command prompt as javac 1.8.0_25. When I type Javac HappyWorldApp.java, I get a new error as "Java:file not found: HappyWorldApp.java " Kindly advice

Comment: @Allanallan where u have saved the program... in bin or somewhere else

Comment: I have saved the program in folder called "mywork"  in C drive. I have manually created this file. Can you give a path to save file in bin. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save your program in the java bin folder otherwise you will get error...

And if you want to save the program anywhere and compile it then you will have to set up the path for that..

```
Try this
Run Command Prompt (found under All Programs/Accessories in the Start menu).  Type

C:\> cd \mywork

This makes C:\mywork the current directory.

C:\mywork> dir

This displays the directory contents.  You should see HelloWorld.java among the files.

C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin

This tells the system where to find JDK programs.

    C:\mywork> javac HelloWorldApp.java

    This runs javac.exe, the compiler.  You should see nothing but the next system prompt...

    C:\mywork> dir

    javac has created the HelloWorldApp.class file.  You should see HelloWorldApp.java and HelloWorldApp.class among the files.

    C:\mywork> java HelloWorldApp
```

for more info 
http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

```
This runs the Java interpreter.  You should see the program output:

Hello, World!
```

Comment: Hi I am getting error after typing "javac HelloWorldApp.java" the error is " 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external comman, operable program or batch file. Kindly help

Comment: Check your javac path on Windows using Windows Explorer C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin and copy the address in .


C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin

Comment: I have set the path as " C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin" Then I tap enter, I get c:\mywork>. Now I type javac HelloWorldApp.java, the error is " 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external comman, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Yes this means that the compiler is not there might be its path is wrong or u have not downloaded it properly

Comment: So, requesting for any suggestion to over come this. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: is the path right i mean is your jdk in program files\java..
or it is 

C:\>cd "Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin"
because you have to give the write path just check it again coz this is the right way of doin it

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin                 That is the path in my system. So I type "set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin"

Answer (score 0):

Compile first:

```
C:\myapplication> javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

Now run with `C:\myapplication> java HelloWorldApp` and you see the "Hello World" printed in command prompt.

Comment: I tried but I got the error  "javac is not recognised as an internal or external error operable program or batch file"

Comment: Have you install JAVA?

Comment: Install Java correctly(put system environment) restart your computer and try again

Comment: Yes I have JAVA, I am using windows 8, I can see JAVA 32 bit in my control panel programs and feautures

Comment: Code is here class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); //
    }
}

Comment: If you write java -version in your cmd?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"

Comment: No sir not yet fixed, I get error message "Javac" is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: Did you put system environment correctly?Type javac -version on cmd first than see this procedure to set them : [set system einvoirment](http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2013/02/windows-8-set-path-and-classpath-java-windows-7.html)

Comment: My java version is "Run time environment <1.8.0_25-b18>". SO I set the path as follows "" C:\mywork> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin". Still I see that Javac file can not be recognised. I manually checked and found out the Javac.exe in bin

Comment: If you type javac -version on cmd you take a result: `javac 1.8.0_25`?

Comment: If I type javac -version I get error message as "javac"is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: OK, now i understand. Your problem is a system envoirment settings with java, you can't reach a bin of jdk. Follow the procedure in a link that a post 4 comment up and you solve it! Let me now!

Comment: I have now installed javac properly, and I can now see the version of javac in command prompt as javac 1.8.0_25. When I type Javac HappyWorldApp.java, I get a new error as "Java:file not found: HappyWorldApp.java " Kindly advice

Comment: You type  Javac HappyWorldApp.java in same folder that is the java file? You should do: `C:\myapplication> javac HelloWorldApp.java`,make sure that HelloWorldApp.java is in myapplication folder

Comment: Problem solved ! I have deleted JDK from Program files 86, and just left the JDK in program files 64 and set a path at the environtmental variables. Everything went well and its fixed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing, but select the solution of your question so the other can see the correct answer immediately! :)

Answer (score 0):

write

```
c:\myapplication>javac HelloWorldApp.java
```

Comment: It would be useful to explain what this does, as the OP doesn't seem to understand why this is required.